# Unresolved reference: TypeToken

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I`m using JSON for the first time and I have a problem. When I try to use and import TypeToken, I get the error "Unresolved reference: TypeToken".

My code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

import com.google.gson.Gson
import java.lang.reflect.Type
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

class QuizActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz)

        val gson = Gson()

        val json = "quiz.json"
        val myType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<QuizType>>(){}.type()
        val quiz: List<QuizType> = gson.fromJson(json, myType)

    }
}
```

What is wrong?

---

### Edited

I will use this

```
val myType = typeOf<List<QuizType>>().javaType
```

instead

```
val myType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<QuizType>>(){}.type()
```

And it works!
(Or I will try Moshi)

Comment: With your code I don' get "Unresolved ref error" but i get `Cannot access '<init>': it is package-private in 'TypeToken'` when i hover over `TypeToken` . Can you please confirm what error you get?

Comment: @MayurGajra Yes, I have this error too when I compile this code. But how I can get this package?

Comment: This isn't exactly the answer to your question, but in Kotlin you don't need to use `TypeToken` to acquire a type, because Kotlin has such util built in its stdlib: `val myType = typeOf<List<QuizType>>().javaType`. For now it is still in experimental state, but it is there for a long time already and it doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Is there a reason why you've chosen (outdated) GSON over kotlinx.serialization or moshi?

Comment: @Павел I just study and know nothing about work with JSON

Answer (score 1):

There's is issue in declaration of `TypeToken`. You're missing `object :` in front. Because it's supposed to be Anonymous Inner Class.

It should be like this:

```
val gson = Gson()
val json = "quiz.json"
val myType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<QuizType>>() {}.type
val quiz: List<QuizType> = gson.fromJson(json, myType)
```

Comment: I still have this error and get another one "Expression 'type' of type 'Type!' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found"

Comment: @Вікторія.Палихата What error did you get?

Comment: "Expression 'type' of type 'Type!' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found"

Comment: @Вікторія.Палихата Can you please update the new code that you tried? & also I would request that you add all import statements in the question?

Comment: Maybe you have installed some plugin that helps to use it or something else?

Comment: @Вікторія.Палихата I have a new project with your dependency. I just copied your code & Pressed Alt + Enter & everything was imported one by one. I have not done anything fancy.

Comment: @Вікторія.Палихата `type()` should not have brackets. Please checkout in my answer. It should be `object : TypeToken<List<QuizType>>() {}.type`

Answer (score 0):

I added these below lines in progurard. It works for me.

```
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
```